# How do I run cURL request in the background in PHP?

Tags: php, curl, background

I'm trying to build some kind of web based download manager using PHP and the cURL extension, I am stuck with one problem though, how can I download and save the file with cURL without having to make the user wait, meaning he will make the request and it will be processed in the background.

Now I can't use system calls (exec, system ... etc) as most of the hosts I work with disable these functions, and the other problem is the max execution time for PHP scripts, but I guess this one can be changed in .htaccess or using ini_set or can it not?

**I've read somewhere that setting connect_timeout to 1 will work, but does not that terminate the connection?**

One solution is to use cronjobs, after the users submits the file he wants to download, a cronjob will check the database and if there is a file in the queue it will start downloading it, but I thought I want to avoid using cron jobs if possible.

So back to the main question, is there a way to tell the php script to run some certain function in the background and delivering the response to the users regardless of the result of that function

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think there have been other posts exploring the options already. Given your constraints, I see two other approaches:

- Make an asynchronous call with cURL to another script doing the processing (see http://www.paul-norman.co.uk/2009/06/asynchronous-curl-requests/)
- Use JS to trigger the long running background task from the frontend side

Comment: I was just reading the link you have posted, this is why I made it in bold, the question remains, will this terminate the connection? Say I have a large file and I requested it with cURL, then set timeout to 1, the will the request be terminated?, plus using JS means the vvisitor will have to keep the page open until the download is finished right? if they close the page the download will stop right? I'm talking about 1 GB files here so it kind of has to be dependent on the server as the visitor is not to be expected to wait that long, they will queue the file and leave

Comment: HTTP is a stateless protocol, i.e. there is no connection the server would care about. It receives a request and runs whatever logic it's supposed to until it's done, then sends a response. It does not matter whether the client still receives that response or not. The response timeout tells the client how long to wait for a response, but it has nothing to do with what happens on the server.

Comment: `http://www.paul-norman.co.uk/2009/06/asynchronous-curl-requests/` this link is dead :(

Comment: @harishsharma here is the archive link: https://web.archive.org/web/20181010063625/http://www.paul-norman.co.uk/2009/06/asynchronous-curl-requests
but these method doesn't work for me :(

Answer (score 5):

```
        function background_curl_request($url, $method, $post_parameters){
            if (is_array($post_parameters)){
                $params = "";
                foreach ($post_parameters as $key=>$value){
                    $params .= $key."=".urlencode($value).'&';
                }
                $params = rtrim($params, "&");
            } else {
                $params = $post_parameters;
            }
            $command = "/usr/bin/curl -X '".$method."' -d '".$params."' --url '".$url."' >> /dev/shm/request.log 2> /dev/null &";
            exec($command);
        }
```

Answer (score 4):

1. Make simple curl request from php like below or ajax call using javascript

   ```
   $curl = curl_init('http://mutant-tech.com/execjob.php');
   curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
   $result = curl_exec($curl);
   echo $result; // should get - Closing Curl Request
   ```
2. Close http connection using header at starting, later write php code to execute

   ```
   // File - execjob.php START
   ob_end_clean();
   header("Connection: close");
   ignore_user_abort();
   ob_start();
   echo ('Closing Curl Request');
   $size = ob_get_length();
   header("Content-Length: $size");
   ob_end_flush();
   flush();
   // BELOW YOUR BACKGROUND JOB/CODE
   ```

If you need more exec time / memory, use function accordingly

Comment: Is this cross platform? (Windows/Linux)

Answer (score 3):

My experience is to wrap your command correctly.

```
$time = microtime(true);
$command = '/usr/bin/curl -H \'Content-Type: application/json\' -d \'' . $curlPost . '\' --url \'' . $wholeUrl . '\' >> /dev/shm/request.log 2> /dev/null &';
exec($command);
echo (microtime(true) - $time) * 1000 . ' ms';
```

Above works well for me, takes only 3ms, but following won't work, takes 1500ms.

```
$time = microtime(true);
$command = '/usr/bin/curl -H \'Content-Type: application/json\' -d \'' . $curlPost . '\' --url ' . $wholeUrl;
exec($command . ' >> /dev/shm/request.log 2> /dev/null &');
echo (microtime(true) - $time) * 1000 . ' ms';
```

In total, adding " &> /dev/null &" at the end of your command could makes it running on background and don't hang the php and apache processes, just remember to WRAP your command properly.